# Push a Viewcontroller in a cocos2D scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I have an app. This app combines UIKit and Cocos2D. 
I have a UIKit menu with a button that calls a cocos2D game. It works fine.

Now, I would like to remove the cocos scene to push the UIKit menu. (Game is over, it's necessary to go on the menu view)

I tried

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView removeFromSuperview];
```

It doesn't work. I don't know how to do.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what exactly does happen after you remove it from superview? does it remain on the screen or it's just a black?

Comment: After I remove it from the superview, my cocos2D view is just "frozen".

Comment: have you tried adding a new view to the app's window? The way i understand it is this: a EAGLView is created and CCDirector is added to that..when the director ends you need to remove the view manually from superview ( which you did) but now the app's window has no view..so you need to add one

Comment: Which version of cocod2d do you use, 1.x or 2.x? In cocos2d 2.x CCDirector is a subclass of UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in cocos2d 2.0 and above:

To Present view controller:

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    

//presentModalViewController 
[app.navController presentModalViewController:leaderboardViewController animated:YES];

//dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES
[app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To add subview:

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.navController.view addSubview:mSegmentedControl];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do something like this.
When you are pushing cocos scene on a uiviewcontroller then add this code in ViewDidLoad method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

if([director isViewLoaded] == NO)
{

CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];


director.view = glView;


[director setAnimationInterval:1.0f/60.0f];
[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];
}

director.delegate = self;
[self addChildViewController:director];
[self.view addSubview:director.view];



[director didMoveToParentViewController:self];


if(director.runningScene)
{

[director replaceScene:[SceneFirst scene]];
}
else
{

[director runWithScene:[SceneFirst scene]];
}

}
```

Here SceneFirst is your cocos Scene you want to push.Just add CCDirectorDelegate in your UiViewController as delegate.
and add this line of code in your ViewDidUnload method

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDelegate:nil];
```

For popping back to your Uikit view call this code on any CCmenu tapped

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope This Help!!:)